# mysql_fetch_array's div onmouseover only works for first result

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am new on this website and I hope you'll answer soon.

I want the Remove icon to show up when users hover on their selected friend, but it only appears on mysql_fetch_array's first result. doesn't work for others. can you help? I've heard that it's being done with foreach function but don't know how to use it, because I'm new at php.

Here are the codes.

PHP:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {

echo '<div id="friends" onmouseover="showRemove();" onmouseout="hideRemove();">';
echo '<div id="fillexit"></div>';
echo '<div id="showexit"></div>';
echo '</div>';

}
```

Javascript:

```
function showRemove() {
var l=document.getElementById("showexit");
var s=document.getElementById("fillexit");  
l.style.display = 'block';
s.style.display = 'none';
}


function hideRemove() {
var p=document.getElementById("showexit");
var o=document.getElementById("fillexit");  
p.style.display = 'none';
o.style.display = 'block';
}
```

CSS:

```
#fillexit {
width:12px;
height:12px;
float:right;
}


#showexit {
width:12px;
height:12px;
background-color:#000000;
float:right;
text-align:center;
display:none;
}
```

I'd really appriciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the html echoed from php script will have same ids for all row elements.

You should create a unique id using counter or something and change your js accordingly. May be you can pass the id to the js method to help find the elements on the page.

PHP

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {

echo '<div id="friends'.$count.'" onmouseover="showRemove('.$count.');" onmouseout="hideRemove('.$count.');">';
echo '<div id="fillexit'.$count.'"></div>';
echo '<div id="showexit'.$count.'"></div>';
echo '</div>';

$count = $count + 1;

}
```

JS

```
function showRemove(id) {
var l=document.getElementById("showexit" + id);
var s=document.getElementById("fillexit" + id);  
l.style.display = 'block';
s.style.display = 'none';
}


function hideRemove() {
var p=document.getElementById("showexit" + id);
var o=document.getElementById("fillexit" + id);  
p.style.display = 'none';
o.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: at laaaaaaast. Now it works thank you so much. I'll accept your answer !!

Answer (score 0):

```
       if($q ->num_rows()>0){

            foreach ($q ->result()as $row){

    echo '<div id="friends" onmouseover="showRemove();" onmouseout="hideRemove();">';
    echo '<div id="fillexit"></div>';
    echo '<div id="showexit"></div>';
    echo '</div>';
        }
        }
```